# How to pair every element of an even-length integer array in C++ using recursive function calls?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, pairing

So currently I have an array `int arr[]` of a length that is an even number. My problem is that I am trying to pair each element up with another into a map `unordered_map <int, int> pairs`. As long as `arr[]` has a size that is greater than 2, there will be multiple possibilities. What I need is to generate all possible sets of pairings.

To clarify this objective, here is an example:

```
int arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

If that is the array, then the map could have these pairs:

```
pairs = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}};//1 and 2, 3 and 4
pairs = {{1, 3}, {3, 1}, {2, 4}, {4, 2}};//1 and 3, 2 and 4
pairs = {{1, 4}, {4, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}};//1 and 4, 2 and 3
```

For these types of problems, I automatically went for the recursive approach to have an indefinite number of nested loops going through each pair, marking them as already paired, and going into the next level of loops. However, some tries proved that this task is beyond my capabilities. Can anyone help me here?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <unordered_map>
int n = 4;
std::unordered_map <int, int> pairs;
std::deque <int> arr = {0, 1, 2, 3};
std::deque <bool> paired = {false, false, false, false};
bool finishedPairing() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (paired[i] == false) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
void pairUp() {
    if (finishedPairing()) {
        std::cout << "\nNew Set:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            std::cout << i << " is paired with " << pairs[i] << '\n';
        }
        return;
    }
//what I need written as C++ code
}
int main () {
    pairUp();
    return 0;
}
```

The output I should get after I did `pairUp()` by hand is:

```
New Set:
0 is paired with 1
1 is paired with 0
2 is paired with 3
3 is paired with 2

New Set:
0 is paired with 2
1 is paired with 3
2 is paired with 0
3 is paired with 1

New Set:
0 is paired with 3
1 is paired with 2
2 is paired with 1
3 is paired with 0
```

Comment: `std::deque`, seriously?

Comment: @273K The input size, n, might not always be 4. Therefore, I made the size of my array flexible using a deque. Technically, though, a vector wouldn't have made a difference. For the sake of simplicity for the question, though, I put it as the least even number greater than 2.

Comment: @Hudson If your goal is to print all pairs and their "mirror", this is nothing more than generating a combination of `n` items taken 2 at a time.  You can generate these combinations using `std::next_permutation` or `std::prev_permutation`.  There is no need for recursion using those methods.

Comment: Your question seems to be of topic here and must be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you getting the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was discovered when I realized I could pick the first non-paired number for each recursive run and cycle through the other possible second terms to pair the first up with and repeat until everything is paired. Also, there was an error. Since the elements in `arr[]` might not be numbered starting from 0 and increasing by one, some `i` and `j` in the code should become `arr[i]` and `arr[j]`.

The full piece:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
int n = 4;
std::unordered_map <int, int> pairs;
std::deque <int> arr = {0, 1, 2, 3};
std::deque <bool> paired = {false, false, false, false};
bool finishedPairing() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (paired[i] == false) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
void pairUp() {
    if (finishedPairing()) {
        std::cout << "\nNew Set:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            std::cout << arr[i] << " is paired with " << pairs[arr[i]] << '\n'; //changed i into arr[i]
        }
        return;
    }
//add portion:
    int i = 0;
    while (paired[i] == true) { i++; } //find first non-paired
    paired[i] = true;//pair it
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (paired[j] == false) { //find a counterpart
            paired[j] = true, pairs[arr[i]] = arr[j], pairs[arr[j]] = arr[i];//pair it
            pairUp();//next recursive run
            paired[j] = false;//reset
        }
    }
    paired[i] = false;//reset
}
int main () {
    pairUp();
    return 0;
}
```

Test results:

```
New Set:
0 is paired with 1
1 is paired with 0
2 is paired with 3
3 is paired with 2

New Set:
0 is paired with 2
1 is paired with 3
2 is paired with 0
3 is paired with 1

New Set:
0 is paired with 3
1 is paired with 2
2 is paired with 1
3 is paired with 0
```